# Mouse cursor jumps to begining of line when typing on Facebook chat using Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, firefox, facebook

According to the title, I have had this problem since I used Ubuntu 16.04.
On Chrome, there is no problem.
On Firefox, there is no problem with other sites, except Facebook.
Problem just happens when I type Vietnamese (using Unikey), English or other keyboards are normal.

Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: I do, on Firefox on macOS. I've been developing React apps since 2014 and I believe this is an issue in their React code, those front-end libs have tendencies to cause issues with inputs and React had its fair share as well. Other than that, I've heard the Grammarly extension often causes problems with inputs on websites, but I'm not using it and the cursor still jumps. BTW, I have this problem on messenger.com, didn't check it on facebook.com.

Comment: I don't know why but it's normal on Windows. Thanks for confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Just click on input setting in tray icon, then turn on "Enable Macro".